Why my VM instance on GPC is not connecting via the external IP?
I'm deploying a html/python app that listens to port 80. On google cloud platform, I've set up a VM using windows server. The app is running (can access via localhost), the instance is up, connectivity test via GCP is working, but access via external IP is not working. The external IP is ephemeral (but haven't changed)
I've checked the firewall rules, as well as the tags, and everything seems in order. Also, the firewall in the windows server machine doesnt have any rules to block the port.

To which IP your python app is binded? 0.0.0.0/0 ?

Found the issue - you have to add a rule to allow traffic to the port in the server machine firewall, even if there is no rule blocking it
